# How to access property in sub method after it runs?

Tags: objective-c

I'm having a hard time working this one out but I think it should be pretty simple. Basically, I have this method which talks to a webservice and I need to return some data from the sub method, the "authCode". What am I doing wrong? How can I get the authCode out of the manager, or can I create a block or something to to ensure that the manager block runs first? Am I even using the right words - blocks, sub methods??? Please help :)

```
- (NSString *)getAuthCodeEXAMPLE {
__block NSString *returnString = @"nothing yet!";
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString];
NSDictionary *parametersGetAuthCode = @{@"req": @"getauth"};

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:APIscript parameters:parametersGetAuthCode success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    if ([task.response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *r = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
        if ([r statusCode] == 200) {
            self.returnedData = responseObject;
            NSString *authCode = [self.returnedData authcode];
            NSLog(@"Authcode: %@", authCode);
            returnString = authCode;
        }
    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}];

//this currently returns "nothing yet!"
return returnString;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An asynchronous method won't be able to return things like you normally would. The end of the method will be reached before you asynchronous call has completed. You should use a callback block to get your string back out. In the success block you would run the callback block, passing in the string. You would want to pass the callback block into your method so you'll need to rename it to something like `(void)getAuthCodeWithCallback:(CallbackBlock)callback`.

Here's a callback block typedef to get you started. `typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(id object);`

Comment: Thank you. For any future newbies, I followed an example here: http://themainthread.com/blog/2012/09/communicating-with-blocks-in-objective-c.html